# Cannot get video with audio to autoplay on blank window

Tags: google-chrome

I cannot get the following to work without the video being paused on load.

```
button.onclick = ()=>{
  var win = window.open("", `Video`, `width=400,height=300,scrollbars=1,resizable=1`)
  var video = win.document.createElement("video");
  video.autoplay = true;
  video.src = "https://test.com/video.mp4";
  win.document.body.append(video);
}
```

I have set Chrome's Site Settings Audio policy to 'allow' on my site, which means videos (with audio) can autoplay on my site without issue, but it appears these permissions do not permeate to blank windows created by the above script (`about:blank`), and so they are always paused on load.

Is there a way to get around this?